# webform hidden component value

Tags: 7, webforms

I created a webform component and set the display to be "Disabled". the problem is that this option only add the "readonly" attribute to that textfield. If I remove that with firebug, the field becomes editable and the value can be changed. I don't want that. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

In a `hook_form_alter` I tried

```
$form["submitted"]["field_name"]["#type"] = "value";
```

and

```
$form["#node"]->webform["components"][20]["type"] = "value";
```

but none of this works. Neither does `$form["#after_build"][] = "afterbuild_function";`

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried submitting the form after being altered?

Comment: Yes. If I change that value, the new value is saved in the database :(

Comment: Is the value always going to be the same?  Or easily retrievable with code?  Maybe you could add a custom submit handler that adds the value into the field on submission, that way even if the value has been changed, it will be changed back.

Comment: So it does, I would add this as an issue because I cant see this being desired behaviour. It should fall back on some server side validation

Comment: I'll probably have a different table in the database and use `hook_form_alter` after all...